xsl:fo table with at least full-page rows for Antenna House Formatter 6.0
I am trying to make table in big document with each row taking height of full page if its content fits or multiple full pages if not
Problem is that with AH Formatter 7.0 I achieved it by setting block-progression-dimension.optimum="100%" to each row, but same document in AH Formatter 6.0 either squishes multiple rows into one (which, if I understood block-progression-dimension.optimum correctly, it technically shouldn't) or row does not take full height
Sample xsl fragment:
    <fo:table-and-caption>
      <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
        <fo:table-column />
        <fo:table-column />
        <fo:table-body>
          <xsl:for-each select="./row">
            <fo:table-row block-progression-dimension.optimum="100%">
              <fo:table-cell>
              </fo:table-cell>
              <fo:table-cell>
              </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </fo:table-body>
      </fo:table>
    </fo:table-and-caption>     

Attempts to play with block-progression-dimension values didn't reach correct result - auto results in some of rows being displayed below cell border

You would expect that V7.0 can do things better than V6.0.  You haven't provided many details, but SO is not suited to large samples. I suggest that you contact Antenna House Support and see if they can help.
